# How to get if JSON contains particular text using MySQL or R

Tags: mysql, r, json, dataframe, dplyr

I have a below mentioned table in MySQL (Version = `5.7.25`):

Tab1

```
ID               Data
YT-1             {JSON}
YT-2             {JSON}
YT-3             {JSON}
```

Sample Json format is available: https://codebeautify.org/online-json-editor/cb57a5ce

The above table contains `ID` column where each ids are unique and `Data` column contains the JSON string, against each ID I want to know if JSON string stored in `Data` column contains value 'Accepted'. If against any particular ID the JSON contains value 'Accepted' in json string show it as a True otherwise False.

Note:

1. For `Status` segment in the JSON there could be n number of resp value.
2. For `finalStatus` segment there could be `specialstatus` available for some ids or it could not be available as well
3. For `finalStatus` segment there could be one possible value such as `Not Accepted` which should be considered as `check it` in flag column

Also, there could be multiple sub segment possible in `finalStatus` segment as follows:

```
{
      "report": "submitted",
      "order": "yearly",
      "special status" : "Accepted",
      "price": "4,451"
    },
{
      "report": "prepared",
      "order": "yearly",
      "special status" : "Not Accepted",
      "price": "4,451"
    },
{
      "report": "yet to start",
      "order": "yearly",
      "price": "4,451"
    }
```

Required Output

```
ID               Data      Flag
YT-1             {JSON}    True
YT-2             {JSON}    False  
YT-3             {JSON}    check it
```

Comment: Post a sample of the JSON and tag the version of MySQL.

Comment: @stud3nt: Getting syntax error.

Comment: What if data contains `Not accepted`?

Comment: Agree @SalmanA, Have to modify as per the JSON.

Comment: Where are the IDs coming from?

Comment: @camille: From database table tab1 usin rmysql library and converted into dataframe

Answer (score 1):

The structure of your JSON is not suitable for searching. Still, you could use [`JSON_SEARCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) function that allows you to search for a specific *string* at specified location(s):

```sql
SELECT id,
       CASE WHEN JSON_SEARCH(data, 'one', 'Not Accepted', NULL, '$.finalStatus[*]."special status"') IS NOT NULL THEN 'check it'
            WHEN JSON_SEARCH(data, 'one', 'Accepted', NULL, '$.Status', '$.Status1', '$.Status2') IS NOT NULL THEN 'True'
            ELSE 'False'
       END AS flag
FROM t
```

The above will search items inside `finalStatus` array for the key `special status` containing value `Not Accepted`. It will then search `Status`, `Status1` and `Status2` for keys that contain the value `Accepted`. Revise the paths according to your needs.

Comment: That's the issue, the value 'Accepted' can come to 3 different path...and i want to flag to be true if even 1,2 or 3 times.

Comment: Add 3 `OR` conditions in `WHEN`.

Comment: You can test three conditions using `CASE`. It would be best if you post a sample of JSON.

Comment: @SalmanA: I have updated the question with the sample json file.

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: @SalmanA: 'one' wouldn't work always, is there any alternative possible?